# Why Docker image built for linux/amd64 platform on macos M1 takes 5 times space than for linux/arm64

Tags: docker

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y ffmpeg
RUN apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip
RUN pip3 install openai-whisper
```

- 1.4Gb - `docker image build --platform=linux/amd64 .`
- 7.8Gb - `docker image build --platform=linux/arm64 .`

`openai-whisper` layer for `amd64` version installs 37 packages vs 23 packages for `arm64`.

Why is there such difference? And how could I reduce the size if I'm going to run the image on `amd64` architecture?

Comment: Different executables, different binaries, different optimizations. That is a significant disparity, but it's not especially surprising. It's likely the x86_64 packages are given more attention when it comes to reducing package size.

Comment: yeah, I thought packages may differ a bit, but not to a such degree. The size difference for other random python packages is not that drastic. Looks like it's an unfortunate case with the openai-whisper specifically. Thanks for help!

Comment: Did you swap the size? :-)